# Is there a way to take a screenshot in MS-Access with vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba, screenshot

I want to use vba to take a screenshot (which will then be sent as an email attachment). Ideally, I'd like to take a screenshot of just the active form. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you need this to be automated?  Is that why you can't use Alt+PrintScreen?

Comment: Yes, it has to be automated. I want to put it in the code so that when a user does a certain action, a screenshot is taken and emailed to an admin.

Comment: Or the snapshot could be saved to an error messages table as a bmp.  Along with other information such as active forms name, workstation number, userid, date/time, etc.

Comment: I posted a summary of this thread at my blog and received the following response.   I make an exemple with Stephan Lebans (OLEToDisk) code to take a Screenshot and converting to JPG and finaly send to Email

You can download here: (Access XP)

http://www.logicielappui.com/tips/AccXP_Notification.zip (in french)

I hope this will help you.

Robert Simard

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use Windows API calls to do this.  The following code works in MS Access 2007. It will save BMP files.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
  bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C

Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" _
(PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, _
IPic As IPicture) As Long

'\\ Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

'\\ Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1

Sub PrintScreen()
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0
End Sub

Public Sub MyPrintScreen(FilePathName As String)

    Call PrintScreen

    Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID
    Dim uPicinfo As uPicDesc
    Dim IPic As IPicture
    Dim hPtr As Long

    OpenClipboard 0
    hPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP)
    CloseClipboard

    '\\ Create the interface GUID for the picture
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With

    '\\ Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
    With uPicinfo
        .Size = Len(uPicinfo) '\\ Length of structure.
        .Type = PICTYPE_BITMAP '\\ Type of Picture
        .hPic = hPtr '\\ Handle to image.
        .hPal = 0 '\\ Handle to palette (if bitmap).
    End With

   '\\ Create the Range Picture Object
   OleCreatePictureIndirect uPicinfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic

    '\\ Save Picture Object
    stdole.SavePicture IPic, FilePathName

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to raise this from the dead, but does this also work for Access 2003? If not, can I make it work in that?

Comment: I just went through the code.. I can't see why it won't work in Access 2003 as long as the DLLs are present.  Have you tried?

Comment: The implementation works .... roughly. There is no check in there if the clipboard content is actually a printscreen, but thats fine since you call it directly. The main problem I have left now is that the image files generated by this are big ... around 6mb for a full printscreen. From what I see for Access 2003 there are no inbuilt ways to make an IPicture into a .png and compress it, do you happen to know one?

Comment: You can adapt code from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813280/how-to-create-a-png-file-in-visual-basic

Comment: Btw, your answer and subsequent help helped me quite a bit to construct a module that went into production today on a relatively tight time constraint. So to thank you additionally I'm putting a 100 point bounty on this answer :)

Comment: Thank you.  I've been helped in crunch situations by many a fellow programmer. I guess they paid it forward!

Comment: Hi Raj,I think there maybe a bug in this code.  When calling OleCreatePictureIndirect for the third parameter specify 1 (I define a constant) and not True which is -1. Otherwise, one suffers from "Out of Memory" error either immediately or eventually. Windows API True (1) is not the same as VBA's True (-1). I have blogged at http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2017/12/vba-taking-screen-print-and-saving-to.html

Answer (score 1):

Use raj's example to get the image and then this to save

```
Dim oPic
On Error Resume Next
Set oPic = Clipboard.GetData
On Error GoTo 0
If oPic Is Nothing Then
  'no image in clipboard'
Else
  SavePicture oPic, "c:\temp\pic.bmp"
end if
```