# Excel 2010 VBA Code to copy screen to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for VBA code in Excel 2010 that will allow me to take a screen shot of a specific range in Excel.

Right now, when I select a range in excel, then copy, the view is distorted from the actual screen view.

Let me know if you have any questions - thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to do it for you? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: What exactly does "the view is distorted" mean? When you copy from Excel to the clipboard, you don't get an image; you get plain text, Unicode text, etc., but you don't get a graphic. What exactly are you trying to do with the range you're copying afterward? I really doubt a screen capture is the best way to achieve it.

Comment: Is this the answer? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456998/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-in-ms-access-with-vba

Comment: Ken - view is distorted when I do a copy of the range - then paste into paint as an image.  So I am trying to find the VBA to get a screen shot of the range - does that make sense?

Comment: Roberto - I have tried doing a copy of the range - then pasting into paint as an image - it comes back distorted - so I am looking for VBA in Excel 2010 that will take a screen shot of the range - not copy and paste it

Comment: Code below works great -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240653

This link worked perfectly for what I needed.

The entire code for 64 bit is below:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetVersionExA Lib "kernel32" _
(lpVersionInformation As OSVERSIONINFO) As Integer


Private Type OSVERSIONINFO
dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
dwMajorVersion As Long
dwMinorVersion As Long
dwBuildNumber As Long
dwPlatformId As Long
szCSDVersion As String * 128
End Type

Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const VK_MENU = &H12

Dim blnAboveVer4 As Boolean

Sub takeScreenShot()

   If blnAboveVer4 Then
     keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
   Else
     keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0
   End If
End Sub
```