# Powerpoint Macro doesnt work on Slideshow

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Can anybody help me about this issue. I found a script to take snapshot from first page of my PowerPoint. it works when I run the macro in normal view. but when i use the action button (hyperlink it to created macro) and click on it at the slideshow, there is no action.
I expect it to take snapshot from my presentation view every time i click the Action button on slide show.. but nothing

this is the script (I do not have any programming knowledge)

```
Sub SaveCurrentSlideAsJpg()
Dim imagePath As String
Dim slideNum As Integer
  imagePath = "C:\JPG\"
  slideNum = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).SlideIndex


If Dir(imagePath & ActivePresentation.Name & "_" & slideNum & ".jpg") <> ""        
Then
Kill imagePath & ActivePresentation.Name & "_" & slideNum & ".jpg"
End If


ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNum).Export _
FileName:=imagePath & ActivePresentation.Name & "_" & slideNum & ".jpg", _
FilterName:="JPG"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are referencing the `SlideIndex` during a slideshow, you can do it like this:

`slideNum = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex`

Here's the full code, with some slight modifications:

```
Sub SaveCurrentSlideAsJpg()
    Dim imagePath As String
    Dim slideNum As Integer
    Dim fullJpgName As String

    imagePath = "C:\JPG\"

    slideNum = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
    fullJpgName = imagePath & ActivePresentation.Name & "_" & slideNum & ".jpg"

    If Dir(fullJpgName) <> "" Then
        Kill fullJpgName
    End If

    ActivePresentation.Slides(slideNum).Export _
        FileName:=fullJpgName, FilterName:="JPG"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay,,,, please help me a little more... i describe more about my problem at top

Comment: I tested this using the Action button, as you described, and was able to export JPG's while in Presentation mode. If this is not working for you, I would add `Debug.Print slideNum` and `Debug.Print fullJpgName` to make sure they are exactly what you expect.

Comment: thanks for your replay

But there is a remained problem. in Slide show when i click the action button that hyperlink to this macro, it takes a picture from normal view and save it to "c:\JPG"... i want to take picture from Slideshow presentation.

for example in slide show when I click at a rectangle, it's color will changed, I set this with animation in powerpoint. so after that when i click the action button i expect to take a picture from changed page with new colour... but again it take a picture from normal view

Comment: If you change the last line to `ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Export FileName:=fullJpgName, FilterName:="JPG"`, do you get the result you want?

Comment: with this change, again it take picture from normal view. maybe I must found a macro to take picture like as PrtScr (Key on Keyboard) and then save it on a file at destination folder.

Comment: Does it have to be "JPG"? I modified [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456998/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-in-ms-access-with-vba) to save as bitmap.