# How to paste clipboard screenshot of Access form to new Outlook email?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I've found a lot of resources for this for Excel, but have not been able to get any of them to work 100% with Access.

I tried [this](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/paste-clipboard-contents-vba/#:%7E:text=Although%20Outlook%20VBA%20doesn%27t%20include%20a%20paste%20from,to%20copy%20the%20message%20body%20to%20the%20clipboard.), but it ultimately didn't work because I'm not working with a string, I'm working with a bmp.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456998/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-in-ms-access-with-vba) post got me 90% of the way there, I am able to save the screenshot and see it in the clipboard, but I can't figure out how to proceed. I've tried other resources that build a new email from HTML, but I couldn't get that to work. I also tried building an email without HTML, and ultimately also could not get that to work. So then I tried to save the file locally and then add it to my email, but the code runs with no errors but doesn't save the file, so I hit a dead end there as well.

I'm mixing methods here, but I will post everything I have so it's complete:

In my Access database, I have a form. I click one button to take the screenshot of the form, and another button to send the email that I want to paste the screenshot into. I was able to create the email by using the query, but this doesn't work for me because the conditional formatting applied to the form is critical, and I lose that if it's just a plain table. Eventually this will all be automatic, the buttons are just for testing.

The form:

[Access form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCfUp.png)

Form code:

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub Command15_Click()
Screenshot.PrintScreen
End Sub
Public Sub Command4_Click()

Dim olapp As Object
Dim olItem As Variant
Dim strQry As String
Dim aHead(1 To 3) As String
Dim aRow(1 To 3) As String
Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objSel As Word.Selection
Dim db As Variant
Dim rec As Variant

Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

Dim preamble As String



'Create the header row
aHead(1) = "AGC"
aHead(2) = "Battery Install Date"
aHead(3) = "Last EQ Charge"

preamble = "This email has been sent automatically because an AGC is due for an EQ charge. Please refer to the below table."

lCnt = 1
ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"

'Create each body row
strQry = "SELECT * From Query"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
    Do While Not rec.EOF
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
        aRow(1) = rec("AGC")
        aRow(2) = rec("Battery Install Date")
        aRow(3) = rec("Last EQ Charge")
        aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
        rec.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"

DataObj.GetFromClipboard
'strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1) 'Insert contents from clipboard to this variable so it can be added to email body

'create the email
Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set olItem = olapp.CreateItem(0)


'olItem.Display
olItem.To = "user@redacted.com"
olItem.Subject = "AGC Battery Notification"
olItem.HTMLBody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)  '"<p><font face=""Times New Roman"" size=""3"" color=""red""><b>" & preamble & "</b></font></p><p></p>"
olItem.Display

End Sub
```

Here is the other module I'm using:

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
  bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C

Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" _
(PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, _
IPic As IPicture) As Long

'\\ Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

'\\ Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1

Sub PrintScreen()
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0
End Sub
Public Sub MyPrintScreen(FilePathName As String)

    Call PrintScreen

    Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID
    Dim uPicinfo As uPicDesc
    Dim IPic As IPicture
    Dim hPtr As Long
    
        Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

    OpenClipboard 0
    hPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP)
    CloseClipboard

    '\\ Create the interface GUID for the picture
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With

    '\\ Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
    With uPicinfo
        .Size = Len(uPicinfo) '\\ Length of structure.
        .type = PICTYPE_BITMAP '\\ Type of Picture
        .hPic = hPtr '\\ Handle to image.
        .hPal = 0 '\\ Handle to palette (if bitmap).
    End With

   '\\ Create the Range Picture Object
   OleCreatePictureIndirect uPicinfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic

    '\\ Save Picture Object
    stdole.SavePicture IPic, FilePathName
    
        Dim oPic
On Error Resume Next
Set oPic = Clipboard.GetData
On Error GoTo 0
If oPic Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "No image"
Else
  SavePicture oPic, "C:\pic.jpg"
End If
    

End Sub
```

This runs with no errors. I can take a screenshot from the form and see that it is in the clipboard. It creates the new email, but doesn't paste, and doesn't save to my machine anywhere. But when I manually do CTRL+V/Paste, it pasted into the email just fine but I can't get VBA to do that on initial creation. SavePicture oPic runs without errors but doesn't actually do anything. There is no "no image" message that pops up. I've tried defining a FilePathName, but that also just does nothing.

[Picture of screenshot in the clipboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKBS3.png)

Currently this code produces an email like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BLmH.png) which removes my formatting. If I delete the table it pulls in and hit paste, it brings in my screenshot:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yieVb.png)

[Here are all of the references I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCY4d.png)

I'm super stuck here, I feel like it's so close to working but I can't figure it out. Any help with this is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can either save the image to disk and insert it using an <img> tag, or possibly use the Outlook Word Editor (from Microsoft Word Object Library) to paste it directly into Outlook document

Comment: @dbmitch I have code now that is supposed to save the image to disk, but it doesn't save anything. Please refer to the last code block of the module code I posted above. I have tried this Word Editor route somewhere along my struggles, and couldn't get that to work. I believe I had issues with Objects not being defined even though I had all the required libraries already checked off.

Comment: Your copied code doesn't compile and is a mish-mash of different attempts. There's a full working example database at https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjYnefG2siYShQdKoG1hiGFQe8Qt?e=iOogYS Start there. If you want to look at the Word Editor route - you'll need more than "couldn't get it to work"

Comment: I started to try your code for saving screenshot and quickly abandoned. Code in this link works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456998/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-screenshot-in-ms-access-with-vba. From there, embedding in HTML with <img> tag should be trivial.

Comment: Also, maybe should empty clipboard after image is saved. I somehow got 'out of memory' error during my testing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the image is the entire app window, not just the form.

Comment: @dbmitch Everything works for me, so I'm not sure what could be going on there. Here is a link to my file. I've added a couple of new things I'm playing around with, you will need to enter integers in the two text boxes in the form to get it to run properly. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AIIlCmTfvfDh09OWMrj2u_UPBysTmqhn/view?usp=sharing That file you shared looks promising, but I can't get it to run properly. It keeps triggering the "File not found" error but the code that makes the file is commented out? Uncommenting those gives an outside procedure error. I'll look into it

Comment: @June7 That link you provided is an example I referenced in my original post, I'm already using it. The issue I had with that example is it takes the screenshot, but doesn't save it anywhere. Code runs with no errors. The only examples I could find of embedding with HTML use .GetText, and it didn't like that I was using an image and couldn't find a comprehensive alternative that uses images. Please see my link to the file. You have to click the button in the form to get it to take a screenshot of the form itself, I have never had it take a screenshot of anything but the form this way.

Comment: I think a zip would be better, here is a link to the zip file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Vi5dAQ44jP_BzYgZ6PsCbOSZwfCMHIu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: All right I've been messing around with that example for a couple hours and still am not quite sure what is going on. It automatically tries to open the picture, but it doesn't create one so it errors out. I tried manually creating a jpeg with the screenshot01 name and it still doesn't see it. So I turned it off and set bautoOpen = False. The commented lines confuse me. I tried uncommenting them and placing them in various locations in the file, including being called by the button press, but none of it worked. Runs w/ no errors but doesn't actually create a screenshot. What am I missing?

Comment: The code worked perfectly for me. Didn't have to change anything. Saves image to file path\name I specify. Called the procedure from a button click like: `MyPrintScreen "C:\Users\Owner\June\Forums\test.bmp"`

Comment: You may post an answer to your own question to follow the format of a Q & A. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @niton OP has not found a solution

Comment: @dbmitch  The OP thinks so. "Solved: please see edit" & "At long last, I have gotten it to work. It wasn't just a single thing that worked, it was several minor things so I will post the new code that does the job.".  Whether it is valid, should be closed as a typo, ... I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks @niton - never saw the edit or any reference in comments - what a waste of people's time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At long last, I have gotten it to work. It wasn't just a single thing that worked, it was several minor things so I will post the new code that does the job. Keep in mind that this code is based on an Access form with one button to take the screenshot, and one button to send the email. It is also not perfect; it sometimes takes a screenshot of a random part of the screen, so I have to click on my form and make sure it's active before trying again. I also sometimes get memory errors and the screenshot shows up in the path, but it's broken. However, when it does work it works fine, and I'm sure all of these issues can be solved so I am going to mark this post solved. Here is my working code and I will note the changes at the end. This is the code behind the form itself:

```
        Option Compare Database
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Command15_Click()
    
    Screenshot.MyPrintScreen ("C:\Temp\test.jpg")
    
End Sub
            
   
Public Sub Command4_Click()

    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmail As MailItem
    Dim colAttach As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment

    'create new Outlook MailItem
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'add graphic as attachment to Outlook message
    'change path to graphic as needed
    Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
    Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\temp\test.jpg")
    oEmail.Close olSave

    'change the src property to 'cid:your picture filename'
    'it will be changed to the correct cid when its sent.
    oEmail.HTMLBody = "<BODY><IMG src=""cid:test.jpg"" </BODY>"
    oEmail.Save
    oEmail.To = "someemailtogoinhere@gmail.com"
    oEmail.Subject = "test"
    oEmail.Display
    'oEmail.Send

    Set oEmail = Nothing
    Set colAttach = Nothing
    Set oAttach = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

And the code for the screenshot module:

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Public Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
  bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C

Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long

'\\ Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

'\\ Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1

Sub PrintScreen()
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0
End Sub
Public Sub MyPrintScreen(FilePathName As String)

    Call PrintScreen

    Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID
    Dim uPicinfo As uPicDesc
    Dim IPic As IPicture
    Dim hPtr As Long
    
        Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

    OpenClipboard 0
    hPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP)
    CloseClipboard

    '\\ Create the interface GUID for the picture
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With

    '\\ Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
    With uPicinfo
        .Size = Len(uPicinfo) '\\ Length of structure.
        .type = PICTYPE_BITMAP '\\ Type of Picture
        .hPic = hPtr '\\ Handle to image.
        .hPal = 0 '\\ Handle to palette (if bitmap).
    End With

   '\\ Create the Range Picture Object
   OleCreatePictureIndirect uPicinfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic

    '\\ Save Picture Object
    stdole.SavePicture IPic, FilePathName


Set DataObj = Nothing


End Sub
```

Out of the blue I had an error for a missing olepro32.dll. Several scans later telling me there was nothing wrong, I ended up having to make it oleaut32.dll and that was a step in the right direction. Also note that you have to do some extra stuff in order to get the img HTML embedding to work, I ended up redoing that entire section and replacing it with code found from [this][8] other post.

Next I had to delete this part:

```
            Dim oPic
On Error Resume Next
Set oPic = Clipboard.GetData
On Error GoTo 0
If oPic Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "No image"
Else
  SavePicture oPic, "C:\pic.jpg"
End If
```

That stackoverflow I linked originally says it was needed to save, but it was already being done by the rest of the procedure and it was causing errors. I just deleted it entirely. I began setting objects to none to help with the memory problems.